# how to compare two gridview and ignore the sequence of data inside

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, vb.net

I am working with a program that need to compare between two gridview.

> So, I have two gridview
>
> The first Gridview have a data that I added manually,
>
> ```
>   column 1 | column 2 | column 3 
>       a    |     d    |     g
>       b    |     e    |     h
>       c    |     f    |     j
> ```
>
> The second gridview data is retrieve from database. The example retrieving result is like this:
>
> ```
>   column 1 | column 3 | column 2 
>       a    |     g    |     d
>       b    |     h    |     e
>       c    |     j    |     f
> ```
>
> Or could be like this:
>
> ```
>   column 2 | column 1 | column 3 
>       d    |     a    |     g
>       e    |     b    |     h
>       f    |     c    |     j
> ```

I used this code to retrieve the data from database:

```
    Protected Sub btnCheck_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheck.Click
    sql = txtQuery.Text
    cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
    drDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    dtDatatable.Load(drDataReader)
    GridView1.DataSource = dtDatatable
    GridView1.DataBind()
    GridView1.Visible = True
End Sub
```

In short, the second gridview was obtained depends on the user input in txtQuery.text, and I want to compare both gridview and check whether is TRUE or FALSE. If the result is the same without concerning about the sequence of the data just like the table above then display true, if wrong then display false.

EDITED: I tried to store the gridview value into an array and compare the array. The comparison is to check if all the data in arraylist2 is exist in arraylist1 and also if the data in arraylist1 is exist in arraylist2. I tried the first comparison using this code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Protected Sub btnCheck_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheck.Click
    Dim arrayList1 As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
    Dim arrayList2 As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
    Dim arrayList3 As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    For a = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
        For b = 0 To GridView1.Columns.Count - 1 Step 1
            arrayList1.Add(GridView1.Rows(a).Cells(b).Text)
        Next
    Next

    Dim c As Integer
    Dim d As Integer
    For c = 0 To GridView2.Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
        For d = 0 To GridView2.Columns.Count - 1 Step 1
            arrayList2.Add(GridView2.Rows(c).Cells(d).Text)
        Next
    Next

    If Not arrayList2.Contains(arrayList1) Then
        MsgBox("True")
    Else
        MsgBox("False")
    End If
```

I don't know why but the above code always display "TRUE".

is there any wrong with the code?
I think it read the row number instead of the string for each row.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Straightforward solution: compare data in datatables being datasources of your gridviews. Just by iterating over rows/columns or with LINQ if you wish.

Comment: I never use LINQ before. Is it easier to use LINQ instead?

Comment: comparing you can take a look at this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083931/find-duplicats-and-display-in-new-datagridview/26090833#26090833 it should be pretty similar without the copy of course

Answer (score 1):

The error is in:

```
arrayList2.Contains(arrayList1)
```

The contains() method look only for single value. Not for a whole list of value.

Comment: Thanks Olivier.... I have solved it, the arraylist2 will always be empty because the gridview2.column.count is 0. I change the code a bit and it solved the problem. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion, I really appreciate the though.